# Angular Controller is not defined?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=homeController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

I am getting the above error

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('app').controller('homeController', function($scope) {});
```

**app.js**

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['base', 'ngRoute', 'routeResolverServices']);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
return app;
```

Comment: share your html file

Comment: wrapping `angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);` in `angular.element` ready will solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because of the order of your scripts (and wouldn't work in any order the way you defined it). When `Controller.js` loads first, there is is still no module named `"app"`. When `app.js` loads first, it immediately bootstraps the app without the controller.

It's best to define one module per file, for example:

**feature1.js**

```
angular.module("feature1", []).controller("homeController", function(){});
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', 
             ['base', 'feature1', 'ngRoute', 'routeResolverServices']);
app.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

and load app.js last:

```
<script src="feature1.js"></script>
<scirpt src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much the reply. I did as you said and it works for me well.. But I have to load all the controllers dynamically on the fly.. I have used requirejs also.

Comment: @vinothini, not sure what you mean by "on the fly" or "dynamically"... but in any case, this should be a different (new) question

Comment: OP would have gotten a different error (*nomod*) if they had the files the wrong way around. Still, good advice

Comment: @Phil, yeah... and I said that it wouldn't have worked in either order

Comment: Ah, I see. [*"You cannot add controllers, services, directives, etc after an application bootstraps"*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization)